Reverse proxy to container is looking for static files outside of the container
I have a website running through a docker container, and I've created a VirtualHost in the host's that is doing a reverse proxy to it, it looks something like this:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    # Proxy for frontend
    ProxyPass /app/ http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /app/ http://localhost:8080/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dss_containers_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dss_containers_access.log combine 
</VirtualHost>

If I go to http://my-address:8080/ I can access the application without issues, but if I try to get to http://my-address/app/ I get a blank screen and several logs of the browser trying to get some static files and not finding them. How can I make the link functional?
This is the dockerfile:
FROM node:20-alpine as build
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
RUN npm install --save-dev @types/uuid
RUN npm run build --omit=dev

FROM httpd:alpine as apache
COPY apache-custom.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/custom.conf
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
EXPOSE 80
RUN echo "Include /usr/local/apache2/conf/custom.conf" >> /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
CMD ["httpd-foreground"]

